# What's the connector pinout and voltage to make a DIY external power supply for a Godox flash?

Tags: flash, diy, power-supply, godox

I want to make an external power supply for my Godox TT685N, and I have two questions:

1. There are 3 pins on the connector (I found, that this is same conector like Canon) What is the pinout of this connector?
2. I found that the voltage on this connector is about 300V. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the voltage is approximately 300 volts and here is a diagram showing the pin connections:

[image]

[image]

You can buy a complete unit for as little as $30. It doesn't make sense to try and design your own. The have complex electronics inside.

[Ebay Flash battery packs](https://www.ebay.com/sch/Other-Flashes-Flash-Accs/64354/i.html?_sop=15&LH_BIN=1&_from=R40&_nkw=flash%20battery%20pack%20-cable%20-holder&_dcat=64354&rt=nc&LH_ItemCondition=1000&_trksid=p2045573.m1684)

[image]

Comment: Why is this voltage so high? How can I DIY make left pin "Output logic control signal..."?

Comment: They are high voltage in order to charge the flash faster. I wouldn't bother trying to design one yourself. It would be much simpler to buy one from ebay for as little as $27.  https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=flash+battery+pack+-cable&_sop=15&LH_BIN=1&_osacat=64354&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xflash+battery+pack+-cable+-holder.TRS0&_nkw=flash+battery+pack+-cable+-holder&_sacat=64354

Comment: Is that diagram looking at the plug of the battery pack, or the prongs on the flash? (I need to convert a Nikon plug into a Canon plug.)

Comment: That diagram represents the pins on the flash body. I added a photo above showing the battery pack connection.

Answer (score 1):

The flash works by discharging a capacitor into a xenon tube, when ionized by a very high voltage pulse to allow conduction. The energy, *E*, stored in a capacitor is *E* = *CV²*/2. Because of the square factor, it's much more productive to increase *V* (volts) than *C* (capacitance). With *C* = 750 µF, *V* = 283 Volts, you get the 60 Joules of a typical high end cobra flash.

Comment: Yes, but capacitors become disproportionally more difficult to build - and larger! - when you increase the voltage they can handle.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way that we can use dc port like this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgSpzLaqmnU
Parts:

- Power bank 12V with DC port
- Buck step down DC-DC 10A XL4016 to convert 12V DC to 6V

Comment: Welcome to Photography! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the video or a description of it here, and provide the link for reference. Also, please disclose if this video is your own link/video.